# Cognos 11: display list rows for null values

Tags: null, cognos

I have 2 simple lists displaying side-by-side to compare the number of students with a given subject as their First or Second Major.

For example,
[the left side has 1 row each for Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, and Senior. The right side does not have a row for 'Freshman', because no first-year students have declared a second major in the given subject.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLCoM.png)

How do I adjust the right-hand list report to show a Freshman row, anyway?
(a 0, the word NULL, or a blank cell would all be fine)

Comment: Can you create a query for the first major and a second query for the second major?
Then go to query explorer, drop the join tool which will create a third query.
Make this an outer join by student ID.  Then have the list use the 3rd query in order to list null

Answer (score 0):

Solution A:
Create a new query dummy-sql giving you the data. With DB2 you could do:

```
select 'Freshman' as StudentClassification, 'foo' as bar from syscat.sysdummy1
```

Union that query to your second-list query.

Solution B:
Union your two queries into a new query and use that new query as input for just on single list.